# How to Set Java jsp Arrays to my Index.html Table

Tags: java, jsp

I am an engineering student. I have just started Java with the school. We have an exam next week. I have some questions about our preparing project.
I'd be very happy IF you could patiently reply to them.

1. Create a Java class called Lane with three fields:
   o days: a read-only string collection containing the names of days  [ How to make a read-only string ]
   [image: Lane Class]
   [image: MainPhoto]
2. How to put into my index file? ( Normally I learned like <% between those %> but get some error messages..
3. How do I make reservation Array?

   reservations: a collection to store the reservations (e.g. a twodimensional string array or a
   list of string lists), where the number
   of rows equals the number of days, and the number of columns
   equals the number of times. The i. row - j. column cell’s value is
   „available” if the i-th day’s j-th time interval is still available, or
   the username of the reserving person otherwise.
4. Last Question ; How to Make such as below the picture.

   Reserved text if the lane is already reserved by someone else for
   that day and time (different username than the user’s),
   o a Reserve link if the lane is available,
   o a Cancel link if the lane is reserved by this user.

[image: 4.Question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are stuck on creating the reservations table?
This is the class I came up with that is pretty close to yours.

I'm not sure what you mean by read-only string, I just used constants (`final` keyword)

We create a 2d array the same way we would a normal array (using `[]`), except we do it twice. When using 2d arrays in Java the first value refers to rows an the second one to columns (`new String[number_of_rows][number_of_columns]`).

We than set up 3 possible values for ReservedState

We populate our array in the constructor

We also set up 3 methods we can use to change values in the table.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Lane {
    final String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "..."};
    final String[] times = {"5-6 PM", "6-7 PM"};
    //this is where we create our reservations table
    String[][] reservations = new String[days.length][times.length];

    enum ReservedState {
        RESERVED("Reserved"),
        RESERVE("Reserve"),
        CANCEL("Cancel");

        private String name;

        ReservedState(final String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    //constructor
    public Lane(){
        //Fill the table with default values
        for (String[] row: reservations)
            Arrays.fill(row, ReservedState.RESERVE.name);
    }

    public void SetReservationToReserved(int dayIndex, int timeIndex){
        reservations[dayIndex][timeIndex] = ReservedState.RESERVED.name;
    }

    public void SetReservationToCancel(int dayIndex, int timeIndex){
        reservations[dayIndex][timeIndex] = ReservedState.CANCEL.name;
    }
    public void SetReservationToReserve(int dayIndex, int timeIndex){
    reservations[dayIndex][timeIndex] = ReservedState.RESERVE.name;
}
}
```

About Including your code in the index,
It would be very useful if you could show us the error you are getting. I think you just forgot to instantiate your class before using it.

```
<%
    Lane lane = new Lane();
    //lane.SetReservationToReserved(1,1); Call this to set a reservation
    //lane.SetReservationToCancel(row number, column number); Call this to cancel a reservation
    //lane.SetReservationToReserve(1,1);...
 %>
```

As for rendering the table with html and jsp I would recommend this resource. It has several good examples on the topic.
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JSPByExample.html

Comment: Actually, everything is perfectly working except the part; when I want to book; I should be able to click " RESERVE". Once I click then it should fill the table as " CANCEL ". 
As we click once more, this time it should again write " RESERVE ". 

It is kind of Boolen. If it is false, click once more make it true. If it is true, click once more make it false. 
I dont really know how to make it. 
Could you also help with it? 

Thank you for your help and time :)